How to convert Segment Coordinate Pixel From Yolo Into Lat Long Geojson
I am new to geospatial analysis object detection. I want to display the object segmentation results in the form of an output map with folium. But I have a problem where when I want to display the results of object segmentation on folium with an overlay image, it is necessary to convert pixel coordinates into the form of longitude latitude world coordinates. Does anyone know how to convert segment coordinate coords into latitude longitude world coordinates.
This is my output result of segmentation object
{'total_objects': 71, 'objects': [{'index': 0, 'class': 'Oak', 'confidence': 96.26, 'condition': 'Healthy', 'segment_coords': [[23.53125, 294.90625], [23.53125, 369.421875], [35.296875, 369.421875], [43.140625, 377.265625], [43.140625, 381.1875], [66.671875, 404.71875], [70.59375, 404.71875], [78.4375, 412.5625], [86.28125, 412.5625], [90.203125, 416.484375], [98.046875, 416.484375], [101.96875, 420.40625], [101.96875, 432.171875], [149.03125, 432.171875], [149.03125, 420.40625], [160.796875, 408.640625], [164.71875, 408.640625], [168.640625, 404.71875], [168.640625, 400.796875], [172.5625, 396.875], [172.5625, 392.953125], [176.484375, 389.03125], [176.484375, 385.109375], [172.5625, 381.1875], [172.5625, 373.34375], [129.421875, 330.203125], [129.421875, 326.28125], [117.65625, 314.515625], [117.65625, 310.59375], [113.734375, 306.671875], [113.734375, 294.90625]], 'color': '#518c9e'}}

This is my code
def get_outputs(image, model):
outputs = model.predict(image, imgsz=640, conf=0.2)  
scores = outputs[0].boxes.conf.cpu().numpy()
masks = [outputs[0].masks.xy[idx] for idx in range(len(scores))]
boxes = outputs[0].boxes.xyxy.cpu().numpy()
labels = [model.names[int(outputs[0].boxes.cls[idx])] for idx in range(len(scores))]
return masks, boxes, labels, scores


def run_inference(model_path, source_image_path):
model = YOLO(model_path)
source_image = cv2.imread(source_image_path)

if source_image is None:
    raise ValueError(f"Error loading image from path: {source_image_path}")

masks, boxes, labels, scores = get_outputs(source_image, model)
segmented_image, class_color_mapping = draw_segmentation_map(source_image, masks, labels)

detected_objects = []
total_objects = 0
label_count = defaultdict(int)
total_healthy = 0
total_unhealthy = 0

pixels_per_meter = get_pixels_per_meter(source_image_path)

for idx, (mask, box, label, score) in enumerate(zip(masks, boxes, labels, scores)):
    confidence = float(score)
    condition = "Healthy" if label != 'DDD' else "Unhealthy"

    if label not in class_color_mapping:
        color_hex = "#{:06x}".format(random.randint(0, 0xFFFFFF))
        class_color_mapping[label] = color_hex

    item = {
        "index": idx,
        "class": label,
        "confidence": round(confidence * 100, 2),
        "condition": condition,
        "segment_coords": mask.tolist(),
        "color": class_color_mapping[label],
    }

    detected_objects.append(item) 

    total_objects += 1
    label_count[label] += 1
    if label == 'DDD':
        total_unhealthy += 1

total_healthy = total_objects - total_unhealthy

output_json = {
    'total_objects': total_objects,
    'objects': detected_objects,
    'label_count': dict(label_count),
    'healthy_count': total_healthy,
    'unhealthy_count': total_unhealthy,
}

return detected_objects, output_json, segmented_image, class_color_mapping

